# TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type 'string | URL' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: deno

**My Deno version.**

```
D:\deno\deno-project\deno-todo-app-master>deno --version
deno 1.2.1
v8 8.5.216
typescript 3.9.2
```

**Command To Run The Project**

```
deno run --allow-net --allow-read --allow-write --allow-plugin --unstable app.ts
```

**And give this error**

[image]

Comment: Add `app.ts` code please

Comment: Not only show in this project. show error in anther project.

Comment: Please post the code you are having in above questation so community can solve

Answer (score 2):

Use latest `std` version. `v0.62.0` instead of `0.50.0` & `0.57.0`.

Comment: upgrade deno version to deno 1.2.1.                                                                                   
How can I check std version

Comment: error: TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type 'string | URL' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'URL' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  return new URL(url).pathname
                 ~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.58.0/path/win32.ts:917:18

TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type 'string | URL' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'URL' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  return new URL(url).pathname;
                 ~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.58.0/path/posix.ts:438:18

Found 2 errors.

Comment: You can get the same error by running this command:
`deno run https://deno.land/x/denjucks@1.1.1/src/deps/path/std/path/mod.ts`
But not-everyone is getting it

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

Downgrade: `deno upgrade --version 1.1.3` and wait for all the sub-modules to change the versions.

ref :
https://dev.to/srnv/deno-1-2-0-url-argument-type-solutions-37m0

Answer (score 0):

use ***`https://deno.land/std@0.79.0`***

example:-

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.79.0/http/server.ts";
const port = 3000;
const s = serve({ port });

console.log(`server running on port ${port}`);
for await (const req of s) {
    req.respond({ body: 'hello' });
}
```